# Android axml horizontal alignment

Tags: c#, android

I use Xamarin native
I can't align TextView and Button in horizontal linear layout
I want to align left and right side ot he screen
[Screen looks like on the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQocY.png)
My simplified code is below

'''

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/background_light"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:minWidth="25dp"
            android:minHeight="25dp">
            <TextView
                android:text="Global transposition:"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textStyle="normal"
                android:id="@+id/transp_glob" />
            <Button
                android:text="Set"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/ButtonSetTranspGlob" />
        </LinearLayout>     

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

'''

Comment: Android layout issues are purely Android and don't really have anything to do with Xamarin.  You might want to [edit] your question to exclude Xamarin and you might get a broader range of responses from Android devs

Answer (score 0):

You could set the `android:gravity` instead of `android:layout_margin`.

```
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:minWidth="25dp"
        android:minHeight="25dp">
        <TextView
            android:text="Global transposition:"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:id="@+id/transp_glob" />
        <Button
            android:text="Set"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/ButtonSetTranspGlob" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Doesn't work But I've fixed it by adding: android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" at TextView and android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" at Button Thanks